# SQL - How to read through student grading records to determine sports eligibility based on requirements

Tags: mysql

I am attempting to determine sports eligibility for students in a middle school using SQL. They have two types of scores for grading.

1. Academic - ‘A’ (graded 1 through 4)
2. Habits of Work - ‘H’ (graded 1 through 4)

A student must have a 3 or higher in an ‘A’ grade and a 2 or higher in an ‘H’ grade, for all their courses

**OR**

A student must have a 3 or higher in a ‘H’ grade and a 2 or higher in an ‘A’ grade in all their courses.

I am posting example grades for two students:

[image: Sample of Two Students]

StudentNo 1 is eligible because even though he has a ‘2’ in Science 8, Science Habits of Work; he has a 3 in the Science 8 academic grade, and in all his other courses.

StudentNo 278 is not eligible because he has a ‘2’ or below in both his ‘H’ grades and ‘A’ grades for Language Arts 8 and Math 8.

I'm looking for help with the code to read through each student’s record, and then each class to determine if they meet the criteria based on their scores by stdType. I started by building a temp table to pull the students and grades to work with. Then I wrote a second query to pull the data for this example – and took a snippet out of that data to use as an example.

Below is the code I used to build a temp table to pull the students/info from our database, and then the code to build an example for this post.

```
--Drop table #tempBWMSElig
SELECT *
INTO #tempBWMSelig
FROM
(
SELECT id.lastName + ', ' + id.firstName + COALESCE(' ' + LEFT(id.middleName,1),'') AS 'student'
, p.stateID
, en.grade
, stdType = CASE WHEN gt1.name LIKE '%Habits of Work%' THEN 'H'
       ELSE 'A'
  END
, gs1.score
, cs.name AS 'ClsName'
, gt1.name as 'StdName'
FROM Enrollment en 
    JOIN Person p on en.personID = p.personID
    JOIN [Identity] id on p.currentIdentityID = id.identityID and p.personID = id.personID
    JOIN Trial tr ON tr.calendarID = en.calendarID AND tr.active = 1
    JOIN Roster rs ON rs.personID = en.personID AND rs.trialID = tr.trialID
    JOIN Section sc ON sc.sectionID = rs.sectionID AND sc.trialID = tr.trialID
    JOIN Course cs ON cs.courseID = sc.courseID AND cs.calendarID = en.calendarID
    JOIN ScheduleStructure ss ON ss.calendarID = en.calendarID
    JOIN TermSchedule ts ON ts.structureID = ss.structureID
    JOIN Term tm ON tm.termScheduleID = ts.termScheduleID AND tm.seq = 1
    JOIN Calendar cl ON cl.calendarID = cs.calendarID
    LEFT JOIN (GradingScore gs1 JOIN GradingTask gt1 ON gt1.taskID = gs1.taskID)
        ON gs1.calendarID = en.calendarID AND gs1.personID = en.personID AND gs1.sectionID = sc.sectionID AND gs1.termID = tm.termID
WHERE en.grade in ('7','8')
    AND en.calendarID = 1058
    AND (en.endDate is null)
    AND (cs.name IS NOT NULL AND gt1.name IS NOT NULL)
    AND gs1.score <> '*'
) AS x

SELECT RANK() OVER(ORDER BY Student) AS RankStudent
, clsName
, StdName
, stdType
, score
FROM #tempBWMSHonors 
ORDER BY RankStudent, ClsName, stdType, StdName
```

Comment: See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 0):

This may be a long, convoluted way (lots of sub-queries), but it got me to where I can determine the students who are not eligible and it may help someone else. If anyone would like to post a more direct way to do this, that would be great!

```
/* 
Select all the students and their classes and grades from the middle school for the period (tm.seq) 
and calendar (en.calendarID) you want to work with. This first query sets the stdType, which is either 
an academic grade (A) or a habits of work grade (H). Working with this data as a base, the queries
below will go through the logic of what determines if a student is eligible or uneligible.
Rules:
    1. Any grades (A or H) of a 1 make a student uneliligible. If a student has both a 2 or below in their
       A grade AND their H grade - they are uneligible.
    2. If a student has a 2 or above in their H grade, and all 3s or above in the A grade - they reach
       eligibility.
    2. If a student has a 3 or above in their H grade, and a 2 or above in their A grade - they reach
       eligibility.
*/
--Drop table #tempBWMSElig
SELECT *
INTO #tempBWMSelig
FROM
(
SELECT id.lastName + ', ' + id.firstName + COALESCE(' ' + LEFT(id.middleName,1),'') AS 'student'
, p.stateID
, en.grade
, stdType = CASE WHEN gt1.name LIKE '%Habits of Work%' THEN 'H'
       ELSE 'A'
  END
, gs1.score
, cs.name AS 'ClsName'
, gt1.name as 'StdName'
FROM Enrollment en 
    JOIN Person p on en.personID = p.personID
    JOIN [Identity] id on p.currentIdentityID = id.identityID and p.personID = id.personID
    JOIN Trial tr ON tr.calendarID = en.calendarID AND tr.active = 1
    JOIN Roster rs ON rs.personID = en.personID AND rs.trialID = tr.trialID
    JOIN Section sc ON sc.sectionID = rs.sectionID AND sc.trialID = tr.trialID
    JOIN Course cs ON cs.courseID = sc.courseID AND cs.calendarID = en.calendarID
    JOIN ScheduleStructure ss ON ss.calendarID = en.calendarID
    JOIN TermSchedule ts ON ts.structureID = ss.structureID
    JOIN Term tm ON tm.termScheduleID = ts.termScheduleID AND tm.seq = 1
    JOIN Calendar cl ON cl.calendarID = cs.calendarID
    LEFT JOIN (GradingScore gs1 JOIN GradingTask gt1 ON gt1.taskID = gs1.taskID)
        ON gs1.calendarID = en.calendarID AND gs1.personID = en.personID AND gs1.sectionID = sc.sectionID AND gs1.termID = tm.termID
WHERE en.grade in ('7','8')
    AND en.calendarID = 1058
    AND (en.endDate is null)
    AND (cs.name IS NOT NULL AND gt1.name IS NOT NULL)
    AND gs1.score <> '*'
) AS x

/*
This query looks at the base data above and starts setting up the logic by appying an 'Elig' value 
of 1 or 2 for each class and standard based on the rules. It basically applies a 1 to either standard type
(A or H) if the grade is above a 2, and applies a 2 if it falls 2 or below. The 1 equates to a 'yes' and
a 2 equates to a 'no' but I needed to keep these numeric in order to make the logic work further down
the line.
*/
--Drop table #tempBWMSelig2
SELECT *
INTO #tempBWMSelig2
FROM
(
SELECT student
, stateID
, grade
, clsName
, StdName
, stdType
, score
, CASE WHEN stdType = 'A' and score > 2  THEN 1
   WHEN stdType = 'H' and score > 2 THEN 1
   ELSE 2
  END as Elig
FROM #tempBWMSElig
) AS x

/*
This query drops the standard type name so that all 'like' scores and Elig values will roll up to the class level. 
*/
--Drop table #tempBWMSelig3
SELECT *
INTO #tempBWMSelig3
FROM
(
SELECT student
, stateID
, grade
, clsName
, stdType
, Elig
FROM #tempBWMSelig2
GROUP BY student
, stateID
, grade
, clsName
, stdType
, Elig
) AS x

/* 
This query pulls all records from the above query for the academic grades (stdType = A)
*/
--Drop table #tempBWMSelig4
SELECT *
INTO #tempBWMSelig4
FROM
(
SELECT student
, stateID
, grade
, clsName
, stdType
, Elig
FROM #tempBWMSelig3
where stdType <> 'H'
)x

/* 
This query pulls all records from the above query for the habits of work grades (stdType = H)
*/
--Drop table #tempBWMSelig5
SELECT *
INTO #tempBWMSelig5
FROM
(
SELECT student
, stateID
, grade
, clsName
, stdType
, Elig
FROM #tempBWMSelig3
where stdType <> 'A'
)x

/*
This query uses the output from the two queries above and sets up the A and H values to be side-by-side
so we can use them in the case statement to determine eligibility. If both the A and H values are 
greater than 1 (meaning 2, which is 'no') then it sets the value to 'Not Eligible,' otherwise it
sets the value to 'Eligible.' Because roundtable does not carry an academic grade, I needed to
use the coaslesce function to read through both queries so that the query can pull values for 
student, stateID, grade, and clsName fields (otherwise they would come through with null values).
*/
--Drop table #tempBWMSelig6
SELECT *
INTO #tempBWMSelig6
FROM
(
SELECT coalesce(t4.student, t5.student) as student
, coalesce(t4.stateID, t5.stateID) as stateID
, coalesce(t4.grade, t5.grade) as grade
, coalesce(t4.clsName, t5.clsName) as clsName
, t4.Elig as AElig
, t5.Elig as HElig
, case when t4.Elig > 1 and t5.Elig > 1 Then 'Not Eligible'
    else 'Eligible'
  end as Eligibility
FROM #tempBWMSelig4 t4
Right join #tempBWMSelig5 t5 on t5.stateID = t4.stateID and t5.clsName = t4.clsName
)x

/* This last query looks at the output from the above query and pulls a students name if they
have any record with an Eligibility value of 'Not Eligible.'
*/
SELECT student
, grade
, Eligibility
FROM #tempBWMSelig6
WHERE Eligibility = 'Not Eligible'
GROUP BY student
, grade
, Eligibility
```